# Unable to set id for row elements in rows inflated using inflater.inflate()

Tags: android, layout-inflater

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
v[i]=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
mainView.add(v[i]);
```

Is the right ay to set the id for dynamically added view? Or is there  any better option for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
v[i] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
Button button = (Button) v[i].findViewById(R.id.button);

mainLinear.addView(v[i]);
```

If you check javaDoc for `inflate` method you will see:

> Returns: The root View of the inflated hierarchy. If root was
>   supplied, this is the root View; otherwise it is the root of the
>   inflated XML file.

So if you pass null to root parameter for inflate method, inflate returns inflating layout, so you can set id or tag or store it in local variable.

Comment: But I am repeating this row four or five times. then Button button = (Button) v[i].findViewById(R.id.button);  works?
I am getting same id for all buttons.

Comment: So you inflate layout and you are looking in it for 4 buttons? Or you are inflating 4 layouts and in each you are looking for one button?

Comment: Thanks.. got ur point.

Comment: v[i] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);  is the key..

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of buttons, you can create buttons and set their id, tags and onclicklistenners like this and add them to the button list:

```
 buttonList = new ArrayList<Button>();

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        button.setOnClickListener(mThisButtonListener);
        button.setId(i);
        button.setTag(i);
        myLayout.addView(button);
        buttonList.add(button);
    }
```

and when you need to use the button again, just call with their id or tags from the list.